A functor $ G : \mathbf{Sets} \to {}_k\mathbf{Mod}$ with $G(X) = k^X$?
I am trying to solve question $1.5(i)$, on page $33$, from An Introduction to Homological Algebra - 2nd edition by Rotman.

If $X$ is a set and $k$ is a field, define the vector space $k^X$ to
be the set of all functions $X \to k$ under pointwise operations. Prove that there is a functor $ G : \mathbf{Sets} \to {}_k\mathbf{Mod}$ with $G(X) = k^X$.

Let $f:X\to Y$. I can't work out how to define $Gf: G(X)\to G(Y)$.
Let $v\in G(X)$, then $Gf(v):Y\to k$. For $y\in Y$, I will use $f^{-1}(y)=\{x\in X | f(x)=y\}$ to be the preimage of $y$.
I want to set $Gf$ as follows:
$$ Gf(v): y\mapsto \sum_{x\in f^{-1}(y)} v(x)$$
However, if $X$ is infinite then the sum can be infinite and so fail to map into $k$. I have seen similar problems before but they forced $v(x)$ to take non-zero values for only finitely many values of $x$.
How should I define $Gf$ to get around this?

Given the low number of the exercise, I wonder if there's a mistake, and either they meant $G(X) = k^{\oplus X}$ which is the subset of $k^X$ with the finiteness condition you mention, or maybe they meant $G : \mathbf{Sets}^{\operatorname{op}} \to {}_k \mathbf{Mod}$.

I would suggest to post this as an answer (explaining why both options work).

Hmmm I don't find that question in my copy of the book. Can you add which edition you use?

@MartinBrandenburg The second edition, page 33.

@DanielSchepler I originally thought the question was asking for the contravariant functor $G: \mathbf{Sets}\to{}_k\mathbf{Mod}$. The following question on the page composes $G$ with the forgetful functor ${}_k\mathbf{Mod}\to \mathbf{Sets}$ so your suggestion $G(x)=k^{\oplus X}$ seems more likely.

The question has been answered by Daniel in the comments. Probably the author meant something else (for example, a contravariant functor, or the direct sum instead of the direct product), and the statement is not correct as it is written. But it isn't easy to actually prove this.
I have deleted the rest of the answer and instead continued the discussion here:

Finding functors $F : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ with $F(X) \cong T^X$
Can we make the direct product $R^X$ functorial in $X$?

